# Copy div and append to a another element in a set of elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-clone

I want to clone a div and append this to another element in a HTML table using jQuery. For example

I want to copy the div `section_title` and append this immediately in the `append_class` span. In other words, the div `section_title` **FIRST TITLE** will be appended to the span `append_class` and likewise.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<tr class="tr_class">
<th scope="row">
<div class="section_title">FIRST TITLE</div>
</th>
<td>
RANDOM CONTENT...
</td>
</tr>
<span class="append_class"></span>

<tr class="tr_class">
<th scope="row">
<div class="section_title">SECOND TITLE</div>
</th>
<td>
RANDOM CONTENT...
</td>
</tr>
<span class="append_class"></span>


<tr class="tr_class">
<th scope="row">
<div class="section_title">THIRD TITLE</div>
</th>
<td>
RANDOM CONTENT...
</td>
</tr>
<span class="append_class"></span>
```

**My attempt failed.**

```
var cloneTitle= $('.tr_class').find('.section_title').clone();
$('.append_class').html(cloneTitle);
```

It does clone but it clones all the `section_title` and append them accordingly.

Any guidance on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I got your point* You need to use `.each()` and `$(this)`

```
$('.tr_class').each(function(){
   var cloneTitle = $(this).find('.section_title').clone();
    $(this).next('.append_class').html(cloneTitle);
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Damn!!I forgot about the each() method. Many thanks. It just worked perfect.

Comment: @Ayanize You're Welcome .. Have a great day :-)